# "jException in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found"

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

anyone can help me  ?

I got an run time exception in my program while I am reading a file through a Scanner...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
at TP.main(TP.java:10)
```

My code is:

```
  import java.util.Scanner; 
  public class TP 

  {
      public static void main(String[] args) 

      {
          Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

          String plainText = input.nextLine();
       //   String plainText="this is the oringinal text and ready for encrypt";
          plainText=plainText.replace(" ", "");
          String key="54312";
          int cols=key.length();
          int leng=plainText.length()/cols;
          int rows=leng/2;
          String ct[][]=new String[rows][cols];
          String ac[][]=new String[rows][cols];
              for(int i=0,p=0;i<cols & p<plainText.length();i++,p+=8)
              {
                  for(int j=0,k=p;j<cols & k<leng+p;j++,k+=2)
                  {
                      ct[j][i]=plainText.substring(k,k+2);
                  }
              }
          System.out.println("1  2  3  4  5");
          for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
          {
              for(int j=0;j<cols;j++)
              {
                  System.out.print(ct[i][j]+" ");
              }
              System.out.println();
          }
  int ky=Integer.parseInt(key);          
          int num[]=new int[key.length()];
          if(ky>9)
          {
              int div=ky;
              for(int i=key.length()-1;i>=0;i--)
              {
              if(div%10==0)
                  {
                      num[i]=div/10;
                      div = div%10;
                  }
              else
                  {
                      num[i]=div % 10;
                     div = div/10;
                  }
              }
          }
          System.out.println("*************");
          for(int i=0;i<cols;i++)
          {
             for(int j=0;j<rows;j++)
             {
                 ac[j][i]=ct[j][num[i]-1];
             }
          }
          for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
          {
             for(int j=0;j<cols;j++)
             {
                System.out.print(ac[i][j]+" ");
             }
              System.out.println();
          }
      }
  }
```

what i want is let the user input his text and this code will encrypt it and show the encrypted text in final

i tried many things but
always i got this error so ..  any help please ?

Comment: I tried to run your code with commented input and its ok. [Proof](https://imgur.com/a/thPxBaI)

Comment: show to me this error 

Main.java:2: error: class TP is public, should be declared in a file named TP.java
public class TP

Comment: what is your ide ?

Comment: Its Intellij IDEA

Comment: okay i tried it and it's work thanks

Comment: but there are a problem in code ... when i write text like " my name is kutaiba "
it's show to me error why ?
and if i write small text it's show to me null ?